# Kendo UI: Get MultiSelect selected values as a comma separated string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-multiselect

I'd appreciate if someone could help with my issue.
I have an entity with field `PAYMENT_CURRENCIES` of `string` type, that should store comma separated values, i.e. "USD,EUR,AED" (or any other separation char).
In my View:

```
 @Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(model => model.Contract.PAYMENT_CURRENCIES).BindTo(context.Currencies).DataTextField("CODE").DataValueField("CODE").Placeholder("Add currency...")
```

The problem is when I submit the form i receive only first selected value in the `Controller`.
I would not like to change the datatype of the field for `IEnumerable`.

Is there a way to receive all selected values as a string with some separator?

Thanks a lot

Comment: An alternative to your problem is to update the Model Value on change event which gives the selected values in the format you require (i.e. comma seperated), but again you will need to set them viewing existing model.

Comment: Please have a look at this Multiselect basic usage example http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/index It has shown the way to get selected options as a comma separated string

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can automatically convert your multi select input value(s) to a single string.

So what you can do is:

- Use a viewModel (ContractViewModel) which contains a List
- Or use javascript to "convert" your input value(s) to a single string separated with any separator you want

Answer (score 1):

Add an array-property to your model:

```
public string[] PAYMENT_CURRENCIES_LIST
{
    get
    {
        return PAYMENT_CURRENCIES?.Split(',');
    }
    set
    {
        PAYMENT_CURRENCIES = string.Join(",", value);
    }
}
```

Then use this property in your view:

```
@Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(model => model.Contract.PAYMENT_CURRENCIES_LIST)...
```

So the array-property maps to the Kendo-Multiselect and translates the values to/from the original field.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement as yours, & couldn't find a decent solution, That's how I solved it:

- Create a new Property in your ViewModel `public List<string> SelectedCurrencies { get; set; }`
- Configure your MultiSelect Kendo helper to bind to the newly created property `@Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(model => model.SelectedCurrencies)
  .BindTo(context.Currencies)
  .DataTextField("CODE")
  .DataValueField("CODE")
  .Placeholder("Add currency...")`
- **To Save:** Now when you hit your action method, just set your comma separated field `PAYMENT_CURRENCIES = string.Join(",", viewModel.SelectedCurrrencies);`
- **To Read:** `SelectedCurrencies = PAYMENT_CURRENCIES.Split(',').ToList();`